# While loop not working while using Tkinter

Tags: python, bash, tkinter, tshark

I have a BASH script running that opens a program (tshark) which writes a bunch of values to a logfile. The script then counts the unique values and writes the (count of the) uniques values from the last 3 minutes to a logfile (count3m.log) It also opens a python script. The python is there to show a window with the values from count3m.log. As the value in count3m.log changes every 30 seconds I want to keep looking for a new value from count3m. I tried it with the code below. It only executes the loop once. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
import time
from Tkinter import *

while True:  

    root = Tk()
    count3m = open('count3m.log','r')
    countStart = open('countStart.log','r')


    minutes = Label(root, text="Uniq signals < 3m ago:")
    minutes.grid(row=0, column=0)

    minutes = Label(root, text=count3m.read())
    minutes.grid(row=1, column=0)
    count3m.close

    minutes = Label(root, text="Uniq signals since start:")
    minutes.grid(row=0, column=1)

    minutes = Label(root, text=countStart.read())
    minutes.grid(row=1, column=1)
    countStart.close
    time.sleep(5)
    print "test"
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When your code gets to `root.mainloop()` it "essentially" stops.  `root.mainloop()` instantiates Tkinter and at this point your program is entirely waiting for an event to happen, not continuing to run code.

Comment: What is `root.mainloop()`?  I think it might be hanging your loop (an endless loop inside an endless loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683217/when-do-i-need-to-call-mainloop-in-a-tkinter-application)

> mainloop is really nothing more than an infinite loop that looks roughly like this (those aren't the actual names of the methods, the names merely serve to illustrate the point):

```py
while True:
    event=wait_for_event()
    event.process()
    if main_window_has_been_destroyed(): 
        break
```

So, you have an infinite loop inside your loop.

In order to update your label, you'll need to attach an event to your root.  Also, set your label's textvariable = a StringVar. Then, update the StringVar in the event, and it will change the label.

Something like this

```py
text  = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable=text)
label.pack()

def update_label():
  text.set("new stuff")
  #update again
  root.after(SOME_TIME, update_label)

#the first update
root.after(SOME_TIME, update_label)
root.mainloop()
```

That should give you the basic idea.  Relate stack overflow questions:

[Making python/tkinter label widget update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918005/making-python-tkinter-label-widget-update)

[Python: Is it possible to create an tkinter label which has a dynamic string when a function is running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047636/python-is-it-possible-to-create-an-tkinter-label-which-has-a-dynamic-string-whe)

Comment: It took some looking at the other topics but finally got it to work. Thank you for helping