# TKinter loading bar with percentages -- specific code

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make this ***specific*** loading bar code also display percentages at the same time. Could someone also help me put it in a TKInter window, then close that ***specific*** TKInter window???

```
print 'LOADING'

toolbar_width = 40


for i in range(toolbar_width):
    time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
    # update the bar
    sys.stdout.write("-")
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Is there a specific part of the problem you are struggling with?

Comment: Yes, as I always get the percentage before or after the dash loading bar, but never at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code i do not see the percentage printed anywhere.

How do you want to print it at the same time? and where?

I personally see multiple options:

- use Tkinter and use different widgets either on top or next to each other and increase both values at the same time.
- using the console output you could clear the console and print formatted strings based on your process (like *"------70%---   "* )

If you want to use `tkinter` you should first create your script, then try to run it and **if** you run into errors you can ask a SO Question with specific errors for specific problem sets.

As Bryan mentioned earlier, this is StackOverflow not some kind of *"LetMeCodeThatForYou"* platform. Nevertheless i will attach some pseudo-code as a hint what *could* be done.

What you could try in some tkinter code is something like:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MyWidget(tk.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # [...] for real code there needs to be more in here...
        self.percentage=tk.StringVar()
        self.progressbarwidget=SomeWidget(self)
        self.progressbarwidget.grid()        
    def increase_counter(step=1):
        self.percentage.set("%s%%"%(int(self.percentage.get()[-1:])+step))
        self.progessbarwidget.configure(width=width+step)
        if self.percentage.get()=="100%":
            #destroy the window / widget / whatever here...
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.after(1000, self.increase_counter)
```

using something like this in your application would update both at the same time, the percentage Value and the appearance of the widget.

Please note that this is **only sample code**, some kind of hint how a structure like you want it *can be done*.

Also have a look over here [Python: Is it possible to create an tkinter label which has a dynamic string when a function is running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047636/python-is-it-possible-to-create-an-tkinter-label-which-has-a-dynamic-string-whe)